# C program calling shell script

Tags: c, shell

I have a small C program calling a shell script myScript.sh. I am getting the value of ret as 256. Please help me in knowing what went wrong with the system call?

```
int main()
{
int ret;
ret = system (myScript.sh);
ret >>=  ret;
if (ret != 0)
{
  printf("ret is [%d]",ret);
}
}
```

Working on 64 bit UNIX operating system and using ksh shell

Comment: Post the code of myScript.sh as well. Without its code we can't be of much help.

Comment: What does the script return, if called from the cmd-prompt? `myScript.sh; echo $?`

Comment: system takes a char*, you certainly meant ret = system ("myScript.sh");

Comment: @Matthieu: Of course. If this compiles and he can get a value for `ret`, of course he's not **that** stupid.

Comment: myScript.sh has an executable to generate the file. I agree with Mattieu

Comment: You really should only be using system() for protoyping. Use fork()/exec() for real code, and better access to results from that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that the `system` function usually works on *nix is that it calls `fork` and then the child calls one of the `exec` functions with `/bin/sh`  `-c`  and then the string you passed to `system` in the child, which turns the child process into an instance of the `/bin/sh` program which runs the command.  The parent calls one of the `wait` functions, which waits for the `/bin/sh` to exit, which it does with the same exit status as the shell script, and then `system` also returns that value.

If you look at the man pages for the `wait` system call(s):

```
main 3 wait
```

You should get some information about what gets returns and some macro functions that help you make sense of it.

The `WIFEXITED(stat_val)` macro can be used to test if the program exited normally as opposed to with a signal.  Normal exits involve calling the `exit` system call.  If this function returns a non-zero value then you can use the `WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)` macro to get the value that it actually returned.

The `WIFSIGNALED(stat_val)` macro can be used to test if the program was terminated with a signal, and if so the `WTERMSIG(stat_val)` macro will return the signal number that caused the termination.

There are some other macros that can tell you if the process were stopped or continued, rather than terminated, but I don't think that they are overly helpful to you for this purpose, but you may want to look into them.

As far as what is actually happening in this case, it can be difficult to tell.  If the `fork` call fails then `system` will be able to return -1 and set `errno` to reflect the error.  If the `fork` did not fail then the error may have happened in the child and be more difficult to locate.  It may be possible that on your platform `system` might do some tests before forking to insure that you have permission to execute the appropriate files and set `errno` to reflect that, but maybe not.

You should look into the `perror` function to print out error messages in the case that `errno` is set.

If the failure happens after `fork` and within the child then you either need to get the shell to tell you more about what is happening, or get the shell script to.  This may be by including `echo` statements in the script similarly to using print statements in your C programs.

You should also look into the `access` function to test if you have permission to read and/or execute files.

If you are using Linux then you should be able to do:

```
strace -o my_program.strace -f ./my_program
```

or

```
ltrace -o my_program.ltrace -f -S ./my_program
```

and then examine the trace files (after the `-o`) to look at what the programs and kernel say to each other.  `ltrace` looks at how the program talks to library function, while strace looks at system calls, but the `-S` tells ltrace to also look at system calls.  The `-f` argument tells them both to trace children of the program as they are created.

## I just noticed that you said that you were using ksh

As I mentioned `system` under a Posix system should use `/bin/sh` or a compatible shell.  This doesn't mean that `/bin/sh` won't run `/bin/ksh` to run your script (or that the kernel won't use the `#!` line at the beginning of the script file to do this), but it could be a problem.  There are ways to run shell scripts so that this line is not used to know which shell is to be used.  The most notable is:

```
. myshell.sh
```

The period and space essentially tries to dump the text of the file into the current shell session rather than run it in another process (this is useful for setting up an environment).  If you were to be doing:

```
int x = system(". myshell.sh");
```

Then that could be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

On my system, `man system` says:

> ```
>  The system() function returns the exit status of the shell as returned by
>  waitpid(2), or -1 if an error occurred when invoking fork(2) or
>  waitpid(2).  A return value of 127 means the execution of the shell
>  failed.
> ```

The `waitpid` man page describes a set of macros such as `WEXITSTATUS()` that extract the actual exit code from the return value.

I'm not quite sure what you're intending to do with `ret >>= ret`, but that can't be right.

Comment: +1 for mentioning both waitpoid() and WEXITSTATUS() (and friends). But almost -1 for not mentioning that system() in general is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The exit status of the command is encoded as two bytes:

- The high-order byte contains the exit status.
- The low-order byte contains the signal that killed it (if any).

Since 0x0100 is 256 decimal, your shell script exited with status 1.  Review your shell script and ensure it exits with status 0 when it is successful.

Comment: If the printed value of `ret` is 256, then the actual (pre-shifting) return value is 512 --> 0x0200, the shell exited with status 2. More or less the same thing.

Comment: @Conrad: Shifting 256 >> 256 is a no-op since the shift distance is usually taken mod wordsize (32). So, it's 256 >> 0.

Comment: @Greg: it's not a no-op. It's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

From the Standard (emphasis is mine):

> 6.5.7/3
>   If the value of the right operand [of the >> operator] is negative or is greater than  or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, **the behavior is undefined**.

So, when you do

```
ret >>= ret;
```

and `ret < 0` or `ret >= CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int)` ... anything goes

---

The return value of the `system` function can be -1 on error.

If your call returned in such a negative value, the next operation `ret >>= ret;` (same as `ret = -1 >> -1;`) results in something that has no meaning: you cannot right shift by a negative number of bits.

When you try to do things with no meaning, C is allowed to do anything ... **anything at all** (that includes doing nothing, doing what you expect, reformatting your hard disk, transferring your bank account to mine, making demons fly out your nose, ..., ..., ...)

Comment: @Sachin: read [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) while I edit my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks PMG, I like the wordings :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your script is executable and in the path, or use the full path instead.

Comment: Indeed, my guess is that OP is used to having `.` in the `PATH`, which is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing went wrong. Did you read the documentation? See:

> RETURN VALUE
>          The value returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is in the format specified in wait(2).
>   Thus, the exit code of the command  will be WEXITSTATUS(status).  In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
>   the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

Since 256 is not -1, the call did not fail.

Comment: THe script myScript.sh is supposed to create a file which is not created. I am not getting the return value 256

Comment: So did you mean the exit status was -1

Comment: @Falmarri: 255 is unsigned, single-byte -1... 256 is not. *And* `system()` returns an int. Unsigned int -1 is 0xffffffff on most platforms.

Comment: Since he is using system() the return value is actually the return value from the shell. So for more precise return value using fork/exec.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you shift the result? Just remove the line ret >>= ret, and it will work.

Comment: Then the poster will get 512, which has some sort of meaning as a `waitpid(2)` status code... how is this related to the exit status of the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on linux and it helped to call the script with system("sh script.sh")