# Call a shell script from C

Tags: c, shell

I would like to ask, how to call a shell script with parameters in C. 
I have found this, but it seems not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char script = "script.sh";

system(script);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "not working" how?  Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187908/c-program-calling-shell-script ?

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: fyi, you're assigning a `const char *` to a `char`.

Comment: You have to mention full path of the script.

Comment: where is `main()` in all of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char * script = "script.sh";
```

instead of

```
char script = "script.sh";
```

Note the «*» sign...

the `system` function needs a `char *`, not a single char (a string, not a character).

Comment: thanks! `sh: add_arp.sh: not found` ive got this error. the script is in the same folder as `c` file. do i miss something?

Comment: but, any idea how to pass some args from C to shell?

Comment: true, but if i need to pass args stored in variable in C?

Comment: @shaggy: Use sprintf or similar to create your full command line.

Answer (score 1):

Basic error: Here you have given a string into the char. That is "char script" can hold only 1 character. For this you need char * script = "script.sh";

Shell Script error: Make sure it is "const char *", also you provide the full path of the script file"script.sh" or whatever command you want to run.

Also you have to add #!/bin/bash on the top after including the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct if you're passing a valid path to an executable.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

You should check the return value and errno for errors.